# Setting fonts in org-beamer with Metropolis theme

Tags: org-mode, org-export, spacemacs, latex, beamer

Environment: OSX 10.13.4, spacemacs 0.200.7

Here's a pared-down org-beamer file

```
#+TITLE: A Presentation
#+SUBTITLE: A really good one, in fact
#+AUTHOR: WallyMetropolis
#+DATE: 05-02-2018
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:1 num:t
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation, usepdftitle=false, bigger]
# Have to set Metropolis specific package options here
#+LATEX_HEADER:\mode<beamer>{\usetheme[numbering=fraction, progressbar=frametitle, titleformat=smallcaps]{metropolis}}
#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col) %8BEAMER_OPT(Opt)
#+BEAMER_HEADER:\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
* Testing
** How does it look?
```

I export this to a pdf with `M-x org-beamer-export-to-pdf`

I'd like to use the Fira font recommended by the Metropolis theme, but I'm unable to correctly install or set the font.

I have tried variations on setting the font, including

```
#+BEAMER_HEADER:\setmainfont{Fira}
```

or

```
#+BEAMER_HEADER:\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
```

in the org file.

and the *Org PDF LaTeX Output* shows

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.51 \setsansfont
   {Fira Sans}
```

To install the font itself, I tried:

```
brew tap caskroom/fonts
brew cask install font-fira-code
```

But I'm unconvinced that this made the font available for an org-beamer pdf export.

I have also tried things like

```
sudo tlmgr install fira-sans
```

which resulted in

```
Unknown directive ...containerchecksum 400c4de374d03934965b5488f37c1b052ade3eda3zzzzzzzz57c9846390b2b78315c6aed2b533a2271bbacabd77c44536b63973bd42e2686f4c6d25d1f4c5b4709e... , please fix it! at /usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210, <$retfh> line 6001.
```

Comment: `\setsansfont` is part of the `fontspec` packages which depends on XeLaTeX. Have you loaded `fontspec` before using `\setsansfont`? An MWE would be good.

Comment: I've added an example. No, I did not add fontspec. I am having some trouble finding documentation to guide me. Is there a way to apply the font without XeLaTeX?

Comment: This sounds like a LaTeX question rather than an Emacs question.  Is that correct?  (I.e., can you make this work in LaTeX but cannot figure out how to get `org` to do it, or can you not make it work with LaTeX itself?)

Comment: Good question. I'll see if I can get something working in LaTeX itself.

Comment: As I said, `fontspec` requires XeLaTeX. See here: https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec. Using arbitrary system fonts with PDFLaTeX is not possible without a non-trivial preprocessing step, so XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX) is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Switiching to XeLaTeX, installing the fonts following a pretty round-about process https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html I was able to get this working.